# RadioButton em flutter com erro

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tendo problemas com esse código, quando executo aparece o seguinte erro:

> "Unimplemented handling of missing static target".

O que pode ser? Como posso resolver esse problema?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: null,
          body: Container(
              child: Center(
            child: Radiobutton(),
          ))),
    );
  }
}

class Radiobutton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RadioButtonWidget createState() => RadioButtonWidget();
}

class RadioButtonWidget extends State {
  String radioItem = '';

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RadioListTile(
          groupValue: radioItem,
          title: Text('Radio Button Item 1'),
          value: 'Item 1',
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              radioItem = val;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile(
          groupValue: radioItem,
          title: Text('Radio Button Item 2'),
          value: 'Item 2',
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              radioItem = val;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Já experimentou fechar o app por completo e rodar de novo? Não tenho certeza, mas o erro parece ser algo relacionado com isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você criou o seu Widget da maneira errada:

```
class Radiobutton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RadioButtonWidget createState() => RadioButtonWidget();
}

class RadioButtonWidget extends State<Radiobutton>{
  /// ...
}
```

Eis [aqui](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) uma leitura sobre `Stateless` e `Stateful` widgets que podem te ajudar, e também um pouco sobre a classe [State](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html).

A proposito, visto que a classe que contém o estato atual "State" nunca será instanciada diretamente por você, é boa prática usar um `_` no nome da mesma, exemplo para o seu caso:

```
class RadioButton extends StatefulWidget
```

A implementação seria:

```
class _RadioButton extends State<RadioButton>
```

Comment: Deu Certo! Muito obrigado!
Eu nem sabia que precisaria fazer esse diamante na frente do State.